# AngularJS Trying to grab name: field from input in html and have static field (likes) with val 0 added as well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

So I am creating an app where I pull a list of Beers from an API. The JSON includes the following fields for each beer {name: "beer", id: number, likes: number}

The issue I am having is I am trying to add a new beer to the existing lists. I only require the name and likes field to POST the new beer to the API, ID will be generated on its own.

code is as follows

```
    HTML

            <div ng-app="beerApp" ng-controller="BeerController" class="jumbotron">
            <div class="all-beer js-beer-slider">
                <div class="single-beer" ng-repeat="beer in allBeer">
                    <div>{{beer.name}}</div>
                    <div>Likes: {{beer.likes}}</div>
                        <button ng-click="updateLikes(beer, -1)">X</button>
                        <button ng-click="updateLikes(beer, 1)"><\3</button>
                    <br>
                        <button class="btn">Add Beer</button>
                    <br>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="beerToAdd.name">
                        <button class="btn2" ng-click="addBeer(beerToAdd)">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    JS

    $scope.addBeer = function (check) {
         var likes = {'likes': '0'}
         $scope.allBeer.push(likes);

    console.log(check);

};
```

okay so this clearly isnt all of the JS I have but this is what I am working with for this issue. As it stands, the name: field gets populated and is what check returns in the console. I do not know how to pass the likes: with default value of 0 to the array so the new item can be pushed to the API in the following format {name: "whatever from the input field", likes: 0}

I am fairly new to Angularjs and am not sure where to go from here. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `name` field to the object:

```
let newBeer = {name: check.name, likes: 0}
$scope.allBeer.push(newBeer);

//when you post, just set the data param to `newBeer`, ex:
//$http({
//    url: yourApiUrl,
//    method: "POST",
//    data:newBeer //like so
//})
```

Comment: Thanks that got me almost all the way there. I guess part 2 of the question would be how can i stringify the check. Right now it returns an object with the name from input. Or is this step going to be stringified once I try to POST to the API??

Comment: @SpaghettiBathtub -- Ah, didn't see your model format. I updated my answer and included a sample API call for how you'd post your data.

Comment: Awesome, works flawlessly, Thank you. I believe I understand how this works better :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$scope.addBeer = function (newBeer) {
     $scope.allBeer.push({'name': newBeer.name,'likes':0});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to push the object, so add the name key and the corresponding value from `ng-model` like this

```
 $scope.beerToAdd={};
 $scope.addBeer = function (check) {
         var obj = {'name':$scope.beerToAdd.name,'likes': 0}
         $scope.allBeer.push(obj);

    console.log($scope.allBeer);

};
```

Comment: This looks promising, but the issue i get is that the console gives an error that $scope.beerToAdd is not defined

Comment: $scope.beerToAdd={}; I have decalred in my answer. You have to add the same. And if you want to stringify just use JSON.stringify(obj);